# Why does my object dissapear when i press 'only render'?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, wireframe

I'm making an scene with some trees that are a particle system, i have plenty of planes with that particle system, but the last three planes i created for the scene, using the same particle system, doesn't appear at all, only on Wire-frame Mode, but disappear on 'texture' and 'material 'mode, and also in the render or 'only render' mode on Cycles.
[image]

What can i do in order to fix this and make my trees rendereable? 
(the ones from the left photo are only a photo reference)

Comment: is the particle modifier enabled for render? What are the render settings for your particles?

Comment: Those are enabled, the scene is bigger than the picture and there are other particles that are almost the same, but those appears on the render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to create NEW particle names at SCENE LEVEL (patticle modifier +) and at OBJECT level (name of the particle system to identify parameters). Go to those duplicated planes which are not rendering. Hit the "+" sign so they will be named with a new name. Use that same name and number to name the object properties in particle name as well (+).